# Livewire method wire:click in button is not working

Tags: html, css, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-jetstream

I try to use wire:click inside the button, but the function is not working

When I tried to click in the browser nothing happens.
but if remove the conditional if(isOpen), the modal is coming correctly.

As I analyzed something wrong with the script but I couldn't find out what went wrong.

Expected to show some modal dialog **sectorsmodal**

Please your help on below code. Thanks.

**Component**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Sector;

class Sectors extends Component
{   
    public $sectors;
    public $isOpen = false;

    public function render()
    {   
        $this->sectors = Sector::all();
        return view('livewire.sectors');
    }

    public function showModal()
    {
        $this->isOpen = true;
    }

    public function hideModal()
    {
        $this->isOpen = false;
    }
}
```

**layouts.app**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
  <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

  <!-- Google Font: Source Sans Pro -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700&display=fallback">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('') }}assets/plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css">
  <!-- Theme style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('') }}assets/dist/css/adminlte.min.css">
  @livewireStyles
  <!-- Styles -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">
  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
  @stack('styles')
</head>
<body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini">
<!-- Site wrapper -->
<div class="wrapper">
  @include('layouts.adminlte.navbar')
  @include('layouts.adminlte.sidebar')   

  <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    {{ $slot }}
  </div>
  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->

  @include('layouts.adminlte.footer')   

  <!-- Control Sidebar -->
  <aside class="control-sidebar control-sidebar-dark">
    <!-- Control sidebar content goes here -->
  </aside>
  <!-- /.control-sidebar -->
</div>
<!-- ./wrapper -->
@stack('modals')

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="{{ asset('') }}assets/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
<script src="{{ asset('') }}assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="{{ asset('') }}assets/dist/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
<script src="{{ asset('') }}assets/dist/js/demo.js"></script>
@livewireScripts
@stack('scripts')
</body>
</html>
```

**sectors**

```
<section class="content-header">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row mb-2">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h1>Sector</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Sector</li>
        </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</section>

<!-- Main content -->
<section class="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
            <!-- <h3 class="card-title">Sector</h3> -->
            <button wire:click="showModal()" class="bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-700 text-white py-1 px-4 rounded">
                Create
            </button>
            @if($isOpen)
                @include('livewire.sectorsmodal')
            @endif
            </div>
            <!-- /.card-header -->
            <div class="card-body">
            <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Sector ID</th>
                        <th>Sector Title</th>
                        <th>Created At</th>
                        <th>Updated At</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach($sectors as $sector)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{$sector->sector_id}}</td>
                        <td>{{$sector->sector_title}}</td>
                        <td>{{$sector->created_at}}</td>
                        <td>{{$sector->updated_at}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <button class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white py-1 px-4 rounded">
                                Edit
                            </button>
                            <button class="bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-700 text-white py-1 px-4 rounded">
                                Delete
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>                        
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Sector ID</th>
                        <th>Sector Title</th>
                        <th>Created At</th>
                        <th>Updated At</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
            </div>
            <!-- /.card-body -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.card -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</section>
<!-- /.content -->

@push('styles')
  <!-- DataTables -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('') }}assets/plugins/datatables-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('') }}assets/plugins/datatables-responsive/css/responsive.bootstrap4.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('') }}assets/plugins/datatables-buttons/css/buttons.bootstrap4.min.css">
@endpush

@push('scripts')
<!-- DataTables  & Plugins -->
<script src="{{ asset('') }}assets/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('') }}assets/plugins/datatables-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('') }}assets/plugins/datatables-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('') }}assets/plugins/datatables-responsive/js/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('') }}assets/plugins/datatables-buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('') }}assets/plugins/datatables-buttons/js/buttons.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('') }}assets/plugins/jszip/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('') }}assets/plugins/pdfmake/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('') }}assets/plugins/pdfmake/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('') }}assets/plugins/datatables-buttons/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('') }}assets/plugins/datatables-buttons/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('') }}assets/plugins/datatables-buttons/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function () {
    $("#example1").DataTable({
      "responsive": true, "lengthChange": false, "autoWidth": false,
      "buttons": ["copy", "csv", "excel", "pdf", "print", "colvis"]
    }).buttons().container().appendTo('#example1_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)');
    $('#example2').DataTable({
      "paging": true,
      "lengthChange": false,
      "searching": false,
      "ordering": true,
      "info": true,
      "autoWidth": false,
      "responsive": true,
    });
  });
</script>
@endpush
```

**sectorsmodal**

```
<!-- This example requires Tailwind CSS v2.0+ -->
<div class="fixed z-10 inset-0 overflow-y-auto" aria-labelledby="modal-title" role="dialog" aria-modal="true">
  <div class="flex items-end justify-center min-h-screen pt-4 px-4 pb-20 text-center sm:block sm:p-0">
    <!--
      Background overlay, show/hide based on modal state.

      Entering: "ease-out duration-300"
        From: "opacity-0"
        To: "opacity-100"
      Leaving: "ease-in duration-200"
        From: "opacity-100"
        To: "opacity-0"
    -->
    <div class="fixed inset-0 bg-gray-500 bg-opacity-75 transition-opacity" aria-hidden="true"></div>

    <!-- This element is to trick the browser into centering the modal contents. -->
    <span class="hidden sm:inline-block sm:align-middle sm:h-screen" aria-hidden="true">&#8203;</span>

    <!--
      Modal panel, show/hide based on modal state.

      Entering: "ease-out duration-300"
        From: "opacity-0 translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 sm:scale-95"
        To: "opacity-100 translate-y-0 sm:scale-100"
      Leaving: "ease-in duration-200"
        From: "opacity-100 translate-y-0 sm:scale-100"
        To: "opacity-0 translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 sm:scale-95"
    -->
    <div class="inline-block align-bottom bg-white rounded-lg text-left overflow-hidden shadow-xl transform transition-all sm:my-8 sm:align-middle sm:max-w-lg sm:w-full">
      <div class="bg-white px-4 pt-5 pb-4 sm:p-6 sm:pb-4">
        <div class="sm:flex sm:items-start">
          <div class="mx-auto flex-shrink-0 flex items-center justify-center h-12 w-12 rounded-full bg-red-100 sm:mx-0 sm:h-10 sm:w-10">
            <!-- Heroicon name: outline/exclamation -->
            <svg class="h-6 w-6 text-red-600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
              <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M12 9v2m0 4h.01m-6.938 4h13.856c1.54 0 2.502-1.667 1.732-3L13.732 4c-.77-1.333-2.694-1.333-3.464 0L3.34 16c-.77 1.333.192 3 1.732 3z" />
            </svg>
          </div>
          <div class="mt-3 text-center sm:mt-0 sm:ml-4 sm:text-left">
            <h3 class="text-lg leading-6 font-medium text-gray-900" id="modal-title">
              Deactivate account
            </h3>
            <div class="mt-2">
              <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">
                Are you sure you want to deactivate your account? All of your data will be permanently removed. This action cannot be undone.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bg-gray-50 px-4 py-3 sm:px-6 sm:flex sm:flex-row-reverse">
        <button type="button" class="w-full inline-flex justify-center rounded-md border border-transparent shadow-sm px-4 py-2 bg-red-600 text-base font-medium text-white hover:bg-red-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-red-500 sm:ml-3 sm:w-auto sm:text-sm">
          Deactivate
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="mt-3 w-full inline-flex justify-center rounded-md border border-gray-300 shadow-sm px-4 py-2 bg-white text-base font-medium text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500 sm:mt-0 sm:ml-3 sm:w-auto sm:text-sm">
          Cancel
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```